# Creating an array of strings and printing it

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

Set up an array of the following musical instruments:
CELLO GUITAR VIOLIN DOUBLE BASS
Loop round and remove the vowels.
My attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *aszMusicalInstruments[4];
    aszMusicalInstruments[0] = malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
    aszMusicalInstruments[0] = "CELLO";
    aszMusicalInstruments[1] = malloc(7 * sizeof(char));
    aszMusicalInstruments[1] = "GUITAR";
    aszMusicalInstruments[2] = malloc(12 * sizeof(char));
    aszMusicalInstruments[2] = "DOUBLE BASS";
    aszMusicalInstruments[3] = malloc(7 * sizeof(char));
    aszMusicalInstruments[3] = "VIOlIN";
    int iii;
    for (iii = 0; iii < 4; iii++)
    {
        int jjj = 0;
        while (aszMusicalInstruments[iii][jjj] != '\0')
        {
            if (aszMusicalInstruments[iii][jjj] == 'A' || aszMusicalInstruments[iii][jjj] == 'E' || aszMusicalInstruments[iii][jjj] == 'I' || aszMusicalInstruments[iii][jjj] == 'O' || aszMusicalInstruments[iii][jjj] == 'U')
            {
                aszMusicalInstruments[iii][jjj] = '_';
            }
            putchar(aszMusicalInstruments[iii][jjj]);
            jjj++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the program stops working just after printing C.

Comment: Define "stops working"? Looking at your code I guess you have a write-in-readonly-data error. You store `malloc(...)` in `Instruments[0]` and immediately after you overwrite that with the adress of the readonly string `"CELLO"`

Comment: use strcpy(aszMusicalInstruments[0] ,"CELLO"); instead of assignment operation.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but identifiers as `iii` and `jjj` make your program unreadable.

Comment: But arent loop variables named as iii, jjj? @MichaelWalz

Comment: You can name loop variables as you want, even e.g `fheruKUHKJ`. The most important thing is that your program is readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to do dynamic allication for this, it's just making the problem more complicated.

Just use an array:

```
char aszMusicalInstruments[][20] = {
  "CELLO",
  "GUITAR",
  "DOUBLE BASS",
  "VIOLIN"
};
```

This is a 2D array of characters, as opposed to a 1D array of character pointers (`char *aszMusicalInstruments[] = { "CELLO", ...`), so you can modify the characters freely.

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1**

- You don't *assign* strings, you *copy* them, after `malloc()`ing, need to `free()` later.

or,

- you don't `malloc()` , instead `strdup()` the string literal, need to `free()` later.

or,

- you don't `malloc()` and assign the string literal to the pointer. no `free()` required.

**Point 2:**

As per your stated logic, the `if` needs a counter `else` part. You need to put

```
putchar(aszMusicalInstruments[iii][jjj]);
```

under `else` condition of the `if` check.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
aszMusicalInstruments[0] = "CELLO"
```

Is not copying the string into the memory you have reserved. Instead it is changing the pointer to point to a constant string in you program.

To copy it into the memory you have just reserved with `malloc` you shall use the `srtcpy` function.

Comment: that's memory leak...right, but out of context here

Comment: You could also just use `strdup("CELLO")` instead of malloc+strcpy

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
aszMusicalInstruments[0] = malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
aszMusicalInstruments[0] = "CELLO";
```

you need:

```
aszMusicalInstruments[0] = malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(aszMusicalInstruments[0], "CELLO");
```

Or even simpler:

```
aszMusicalInstruments[0] = strdup("CELLO");
```

The advantage of the last solution is that you d'ont have to worry about the length of the string.